# my stored procedured worlking properly in local mssql but but not in godaddy mylittleadmin

Tags: sql-server

> this is my sql code for login when execte it in my local mssql server
>   working properly but when i exected in godaddy's mylittleadmin is not

```
alter proc  [dbo].[Loginuser] 
 @Username nvarchar(100),
 @Password nvarchar(100)

as 
begin 

Declare @Retrycount int
Declare @count int
Declare @Accountlocked bit
Declare @Rolename nvarchar(20)

select @Accountlocked = Islocked 
  from tbl_Userinfo where Email = @Username
if(@Accountlocked = 1)
begin
select 1 as Accountlocked ,0 as authenticated,0 as Retryattempts
end
else
begin
select @count = count(Email) from tbl_Userinfo where Email=@Username and [Password]=@Password

if(@count=1)
    begin
 update  tbl_Userinfo set Retryattempts = 0 
 where Email = @Username
 select 0 as Accountlocked,1 as authenticated,0 as Rertyattempts

UPDATE tbl_Userinfo
        SET LastLogin =  GETDATE()
        WHERE Email = @Username

SELECT @Rolename = RoleName FROM tbl_Roles  WHERE RoleId = (select RoleId from tbl_Userinfo where Email=@Username and [Password]=@Password)

SELECT 1 as [ReturnCode], @Username as [Uname], @Rolename as [Roles] 

end
 else
begin
select @Retrycount = IsNull(Retryattempts,0)
  from tbl_Userinfo  where Email = @Username
set @Retrycount=@Retrycount+1
if(@Retrycount <= 3)
    begin
  update  tbl_Userinfo set Retryattempts = @Retrycount
  where Email = @Username
  select 0 as Accountlocked,0 as authenticated,@Retrycount as  Retryattempts
    end

 else
    begin
update tbl_Userinfo set Retryattempts = @Retrycount,
 Islocked = 1,Lockeddatetime = GETDATE()
 where Email = @Username
 select 0 as Accountlocked,0 as authenticated,0 as Retryattempts
  end
  end
  end
  end
```

[this is output i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euPMq.png)

**I want output like in given image but it is working correct in local mssql server when i execute it in godaddy's mylitleadmin it is returning null in Roles columns**
[This is role table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj4PB.png)

> Can any help me with solution please.

Comment: You should NEVER store passwords in clear text. There are very few absolutes in sql server but this is one of them. Passwords should be salted and hashed every single time with no exception.

Comment: actually i'm testing in mylitle admin server , i will hash password later.
But it is not working as in mssql server.